# Splitting a column into multiple using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'favs':{0:'chicken_panfry1_t360_ketchup',
                          1:'chicken_bake2_t450_out_bbq',
                          2:'chicken_boiled2_season_gravy'}})
```

That looks like this

```
   favs
0 chicken_panfry1_t360_ketchup
1 chicken_bake2_t450_out_bbq
2 chicken_boiled2_season_gravy
```

I would like to split the column at the last underscore to create 2 new columns that look like this.

```
 favs                              recipe                     sauce
0 chicken_panfry1_t360_ketchup     chicken_panfry1_t360       ketchup
1 chicken_bake2_t450_out_bbq       chicken_bake2_t450_out     bbq
2 chicken_boiled2_season_gravy     chicken_boiled2_season     gravy
```

This is what I've tried

```
df[['recipe','sauce']]=df['favs'].str.split(r'.*_', expand=True)
```

This creates the sauce column correctly but the recipe column is blank. It looks like this. Unsure of how to correct it.

```
 favs                              recipe       sauce
0 chicken_panfry1_t360_ketchup                  ketchup
1 chicken_bake2_t450_out_bbq                    bbq
2 chicken_boiled2_season_gravy                  gravy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `Series.str.extract` with the `(.*)_(.*)` regex pattern:

```py
df[['recipe','sauce']]=df['favs'].str.extract(r'(.*)_(.*)', expand=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HRXweU/1).

The `(.*)_(.*)` regex matches and captures the part before the last `_` into Group 1 (with the first `(.*)`) and the part after last `_` into the second column (with the second `(.*)`).

Answer (score 2):

No need for a regex, you can simply `rsplit` limiting to 1 split:

```
df[['recipe','sauce']] = df['favs'].str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
```

output:

```
                           favs                  recipe    sauce
0  chicken_panfry1_t360_ketchup    chicken_panfry1_t360  ketchup
1    chicken_bake2_t450_out_bbq  chicken_bake2_t450_out      bbq
2  chicken_boiled2_season_gravy  chicken_boiled2_season    gravy
```